# Used wrong power adaptor for months. Why did it work then suddenly stop working?

Tags: power-supply

So I have this "Open" sign I use. For months I was using a power adaptor that was supplying 12 V - 2.5 A. The "Open" sign requires 12 V - 3.5 A. For months I was using this power adaptor, I noticed it wasn't as bright as it once used to be. Although I thought that was just my eyes.... One day the "Open" sign stopped turning on. I wasn't sure what was going on so I decided to inspect. That is when I noticed, changed to the proper supply and voilah it works, and has been working for months, full brightness too.

This has been bothering me for a while as I cannot explain why it was partially working, then no longer working with that adaptor. The adaptor still works fine as I use it for what it was meant for. Also if something was damaged in doing this why does it work perfectly now? Not looking for guarantees, theoreticals would be fine.

If this helps the open sign is very similar to this one: [Open Sign](https://www.amazon.ca/Royal-Sovereign-Business-Writing-RSB-1342E/dp/B00EWO1JPK/ref=asc_df_B00EWO1JPK/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=293036785435&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=13193359105249456015&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9047854&hvtargid=pla-569239549392&psc=1),.

Comment: did you try it on the sign after you unplugged it and let it sit for a while?

Comment: This is a very broad question. It is likely that the power adapter is actually damaged, now. Enough that it no longer works when attached to a high-current sign that it was never intended for but not so much that it cannot serve its intended purpose. But diagnosing the specifics would require a great deal more than you've written here.

Comment: possible thermal cutout switch inside the power adapter

Comment: @jsotola yes I did unplug it and let it sit. Not sure if it was long enough. It did not feel warm, actually cold as it was in an off state prior for at least 12 hours. Although I can't say that for a fact so thank you for the response.

Comment: @jonk I do realise it is very broad, which is why it took me so long to ask as I thought maybe I could reason it out. I was wrong. Thank you for your feedback.  Il try and think of more information I can provide and edit the post.

Comment: if the power adapter has a model number, then there is a slim chance that you may be able to find a datasheet

Comment: @lightweightmcgee I'm not complaining. Get that right. I totally understand why you may be curious. I might also be. The difference is that if my interest were sufficient, I'd just crack it open and spend time finding out. (I probably wouldn't get that curious, because my wife always has *more important* things for me to waste my time on. But that's the compromise that comes from being responsible for my family, the families of all three of my children and grandchildren -- all who live with me here.) I'm just suggesting it's probably been heat-damaged but not to the point of complete failure.

Comment: @lightweightmcgee For example, when too much current flows through an aluminization within an IC, metal migration takes place at a wildly increasing rate. Over time, this diminishes function and can lead to complete failure. That's only one such example. But tracking down the exact reason could require the removal of the epoxy casing and then a micrograph (electron microscope perhaps, x-rays possibly, and maybe even the use of gallium ion beam milling) to uncover the precise situation.

Comment: @jonk 
Thank you for taking the time to provide me with some insight. I am extremely pleased with your response. Best wishes good sir.

Comment: Olympic sprinters don't do well in Olympic long distance races. They can run for a while but eventually give up the ghost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Power Adapters have a maximum current rating due to temperature rise and/or voltage drop due to excess resistance in the regulator parts.   They may have over-temperature protection (OTP) and/or over-current protection. (OCP).

Over-loading current can also reduce the voltage which on LEDs also reduces the current rapidly such that it might not initially trigger OCP or OTP but unable to produce full voltage as the heat causes FET resistance to increase and reference voltages can decrease.  Overload will increase the temperature inside the power supply and rapidly age parts (e-caps in particular) and may increase the resistance which in turn raises the temperature.  Once the OTP threshold is reached, it shuts down abruptly.

It is wise to have a current rating greater than the load by some margin so it does not operate at max temperature.  This will also naturally depend on how many LEDs are active so the load is not exact precise but ought to be worst case with the mos LEDs on.

Lesson  learnt: Use the correct supply.  Buy a spare, as hot supplies don't last as long you would like.

Comment: Your answer has provided me with both what, may have, happened and how to prevent it in the future. Thank you!